# How do I backup my wallet

Tags: wallets, security, backup

I'm using the Ethereum Wallet.

When I click - `File > Backup > Accounts`, it does nothing.

Can't see the UTC keystore files in `AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet`

What am I doing wrong?

I have 1 Ether

Is writing down your wallet address worth anything?

Comment: I did a search on my PC and it turns out there was a folder on one of my other HDD's under Ethereum with the folders Geth, Keystore and Mist so i'd assume that's the one.